# 500 errors not reported as log level error when using php73

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

With php72 or php73 the 500 error response codes are no longer identified in Google Cloud logging with the red log level "Error"

How can I resolve this?

[image]

I suspect it is related to this change in php7:

> The entrypoint field uses the built-in serve command, which is a
>   program within the PHP 7 runtime that starts up the php-fpm
>   implementation and a webserver in the background. This webserver
>   routes all traffic to the provided PHP file using the front controller
>   design pattern
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#application_startup

I'm using App Engine standard with this app.yaml

```
runtime: php73
entrypoint: serve controller.php
```

Comment: You may want to file a bug

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be a bug. I tried to run a PHP7 app on App Engine to make it crash and I was able to see in Stackdriver the same issue as you, something that doesn't happen on PHP5. You could check any progress for that issue to get resolved [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/144573569).

Comment: I got an unsatisfactory answer from Google saying I have to essentially catch my 500 errors: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144182674